# Add theme color palette picker

Tags: 8, theming

I have a multisite in Drupal 8 eg. same codebase, differrent db. The client is asking for different color scheme for each subsite. I was thinking of implementing somehow Bartik's color picker, but have no idea how. The current theme is not derived from Bartik. 
O the question is how can I implement color picker in my custom subtheme?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by the color module which is a part of Drupal core.

> The Color module allows users with the Administer site configuration permission to quickly and easily change the color scheme of themes that have been built to be compatible with it. In order for the color module to work, a theme must be specifically designed to use the color changing features.

Here's a great guide to integrate to the color module in Drupal 8.

[Integrating the color module into your drupal 8 theme](https://medium.codekoalas.com/integrating-the-color-module-into-your-drupal-8-theme-5e9b32db690d)

Comment: Thanks @Jdrupal. I have done the way it's described in the link. I didn't need sass or scss(this is what i was afraid of). Only the color.inc file and a separate css file. The rest is done by D8.